# Is there a command to list the compressed file sizes for files within a .zip file?

Tags: files, compression, zip, size

I'd like to see the absolute size in bytes of each file that has been compressed into single zip file.  Having read the zip man page, I'm not sure that that utility can do it.  This is on Mac OS X.

Something like:

```
$zip list myarchive.zip

file1.jpg 100 bytes compressed 3000 bytes uncompressed
file2.jpg 130 bytes compressed 3440 bytes uncompressed
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the `unzip` utility with the `-v` flag:

```
unzip -v files.zip

Archive:  files.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 11-23-2011 15:02 00000000  file1
       0  Stored        0   0% 11-23-2011 15:02 00000000  file2
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       0                0   0%                            2 files
```

Note: The file sizes here are `0` because I made test files of zero length.

Answer (score 7):

Doesn't `unzip -l somefile.zip` do exactly what you want?

Comment: `unzip -l` does not show the original size vs compressed size, it only show the original size (decompressed).

Answer (score 4):

`unzip -l` gives **uncompressed files size** and `-v` lists archive files verbosely, adding to the basic `-l` info the compression  method,  **file's compressed size**, compression ratio and more.